If $A$ is Borel measurable, is $\int_0^21_{A}(x)\int_{x-4}^x\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}x=0$?
Consider the simple double integral $I(A)=\int_0^21_A(x)\int_{x-4}^x\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}x$ where $A$ is a set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. I want to check the very simply question if $I(A)=0$ for all $A$, but I am stuck trying to prove or disprove it.
Does anyone have a hint?
